# Eclipse and Python 3: why does printf() from ctypes display in console output after subsequent print() statements

Tags: python, eclipse, printf, pydev, ctypes

I am running Eclipse with PyDev and Python 3.2 on Windows Vista, and was working through a tutorial on Python and ctypes.

However, I found that when I call msvcrt.printf() to print a string, this is not displayed in the console output for Eclipse until all other print statements have displayed.

Here is the exact code I use:

```
from ctypes import *

msvcrt = cdll.msvcrt
message_string = "Hello Worlds!\n"

printf = msvcrt.printf
print(printf("Testing: %s".encode('ascii'),message_string.encode('ascii')))


print("foo")

print("why!?")
```

and here is the output:

```
23
foo
why!?
Testing: Hello Worlds!
```

The only explanations I have seen elsewhere (for C in general) mention how printf is buffered and needs a newline before displaying, but there is a newline in the string, and I also added one directly to the printf statement ('printf("Testing: %s\n",...') and it made no difference.

I want to work in Eclipse, I don't want to have to keep opening a command prompt every time i want to test scripts, so is there any way I can fix this ordering in the console output?  And why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

If the C standard library thinks `stdout` is connected to a file or a pipe rather than a console, it will block-buffer its output.  You can work around this by issuing a `fflush` after `printf`:

```
msvcrt.fflush(msvcrt.stdout)
```

You may also be able to force `stdout` into non-buffered mode:

```
msvcrt.setvbuf(msvcrt.stdout, None, _IONBF, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but as for the fixes, I get this error:
"AttributeError: function 'stdout' not found"

Comment: Getting a pointer to stdout from msvcrt could be quite difficult; see http://osdir.com/ml/python.ctypes/2005-09/msg00019.html

Answer (score 0):

Although this does not answer your question but printf is returning `23` which is the number of printed characters, you could replace it with `sprintf` and that will return the string and will be displayed in the console in the right expected order.

However, I don't see a reason for using mscvcrt's printf when you can do the same with python.

Comment: I was just following a tutorial on ctypes, which I plan to use for functions other than printf later.  The reason i wanted to understand this and get it to work is because if I can't understand what is happening with this simple task how can I expect to understand more complex ones?