# Calling sequence of functions

Tags: python, ctypes

```
from ctypes import cdll

libc = cdll.msvcrt
message = "Hello World!\n"
length = libc.printf("Printing by msvcrt: %s", message)
print length
```

The result of the code above:

```
33
Printing by msvcrt: Hello World!
```

Why is the length of the string printed first, rather than the string itself?

Comment: I was able to reproduce this.. maybe something to do with the C functions needing to compile first, and the python print being interpreted rather than compiled?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse and Python 3: why does printf() from ctypes display in console output after subsequent print() statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653751/eclipse-and-python-3-why-does-printf-from-ctypes-display-in-console-output-af)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two separate instances of C runtime libraries.  `msvcrt.dll` and whatever version Python is linked to.  My Python 2.7 version uses `msvcr90.dll`, which is from Visual Studio 2008.

This means there are two separate instances of the buffered stdout, and in your case Python's buffered I/O is flushing before the other instance.  I could not reproduce the output of your script.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `msvcr.fflush(None)` after the output of `libc.printf()`:

[why does printf() from ctypes display in console output after subsequent print() statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653751/eclipse-and-python-3-why-does-printf-from-ctypes-display-in-console-output-af)

[stdout redirection with ctypes and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942874/stdout-redirection-with-ctypes-and-python)

[(ctypes)msvcrt.printf and print in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939657/ctypesmsvcrt-printf-and-print-in-python)

Answer (score -1):

You have fired up two separate execution threads: one in Python, one in C (I'm oversimplifying).  The Python one finished first.

Another way to get this effect is to generate a stack trace (execution error) in Python, just after executing some very simple (fast) code with print statements.  The stack trace can get interleaved with the print output.

Comment: No, it didn't start a new thread.  The Python code is simply calling a C library function that buffers the output.